# To pop to three vectors in Matlab by using Java's Stack

Tags: java, matlab

I have a function

```
data1 = conv(data(75:138),hamming(64)); [B,T,F] = tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1));
```

I cannot push to three the stacks `[B,T,F]` so it is better to make one stack instead

```
BTF = java.util.Stack();
```

and now run

```
data1 = conv(data(1:64),hamming(64)); BTF.push(tfrwv(data1, 1:length(data1), length(data1)));
```

and now is the problem of popping the data from BTF into vectors B, T and F.
I run unsuccessfully

```
[B,T,F] = BTF.pop();
```

The command `BTF.pop()` returns 127x127 double.
So I need to handle the stack by some other function or start from scratch, probably from three stacks.

**How can you pop from one stack the data of three variables into three vectors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is, that `BTF.push(tfrwv(...));` pushes the first output argument only. Use `[B,T,F]=tfrwv(...);BTF.push({B,T,F});` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BTF.push({B,T,F})` instead, to deliver all the arguments